# Markov inequality to find bound on the probablity over an interval

Tags: estimation, parameter-estimation

Is it possible to use Markov inequality, as given in the following, to find bound on the probability over an interval?

$$P[X \ge a] \le \frac{E[X]}{a}$$

For example, consider this problem. The number of letters delivered by a postman during a day is a random variable `X` with expected value $E[X]=100$. So, can we use Markov inequality to find a lower bound on the probability that the number of letters delivered in a day lies between 75 and 125 i.e. $P[75\le X<125]$?

If variance is also available, Chebyshev inequality can be used for the above problem. However, in the absence of variance, can we use Markov inequality to find a bound on the probability over an interval?

Comment: Seem no big problem if calculate lower bound since $P[X \geq A] \leq  \frac{E(X)}{A}$    
But searching upper bound we risk to lose big part of interval since $P[X \leq A] \geq 1 - \frac{E(X)}{A}$.  
In any case if there is no any info and can't measure varience, then can try to estimate bounds like you say

Comment: I think that for any desired value of $E[X]$, you can construct a nonnegative random variable $X$ such that $P(75 \le X < 125)=0$. So I don't think there is a meaningful lower bound without more assumptions.

Comment: @spiral_being: If I use $P[X \ge A] \le \frac{E[X]}{A}$ with $A=75$, then this gives $P[X \ge 75] \le \frac{4}{3}$ which is $>1$. Should not it be smaller than the maximum value 1?

Comment: As it is only a bound and not a probability, the value $\frac{4}{3}$ for the bound is permissible though!